# Graph API Access without HTTPS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ip

We have a Facebook app running on our production having HTTPS and it works fine.
For same app we have a development/stage setup but don’t have HTTPS.
Till 2012-02-23, both the server works fine. 
Now our app on development/stage server throws below error:

1. CurlException: 28: connect() timed out!
2. Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

I have question:

1. Is it mandatory to have a HTTPS to communicate with Graph API?
2. Or, Facebook does blacklisting of IP – if so how to make IP white list?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible answers may also exist in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533345/is-it-mandatory-to-have-a-https-to-communicate-with-graph-api/9533420#9533420

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if passing an access token ( which is needed for most API calls) you must use HTTPS
2. Possibly, but it's far more likely to be a firewall problem on your side - Facebook would accept the connection but return an error message, but you're not even getting a connection to Facebook