# Is it mandatory to have a HTTPS to communicate with Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, https, whitelist

Does anybody knows is it mandatory to have a HTTPS to communicate with Graph API?

Actually, we have a Facebook app running on our production having HTTPS and it works fine. For same app we have a development/stage setup but don’t have HTTPS. Till 2012-02-23, both the server works fine. Now our app on development/stage server throws below error:

CurlException: 28: connect() timed out!

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

I’m just wondering if its a HTTPS problem or Facebook does blacklisting of IP.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529207/graph-api-access-without-https

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like HTTPS is required for this.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        dl('php_openssl.dll');
    } else {
        dl('openssl.so');
    }
}

?>
```

or add openssl.so into your php.ini and restart server

p.s. You must use HTTPS when sending access_token