# Graph API - Connection time out

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, debian

I'm trying to use Graph API requests via file_get_content (PHP) on my production server (ssh, Debian) but it doesn't work although it works fine on my localhost.
It returns: connection time out.

I've been through many threads regarding my issue and i've found this one : [Graph API Access without HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529207/graph-api-access-without-https)

It says that I must use HTTPS on my server. But then, why is it working on my localhost if it needs HTTPS ? Is there any other possibilities ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Likely your hosting provider does not allow `file_get_contents` ... look at this topic as an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working

Comment: it allows it but as i use 4 file_get_content in my script; then it returns a connection time out. If I use only one file_get_content for a test, it works. But I need those 4 file_get_content..

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; show code, and describe exactly under what conditions the error happens.

Comment: my issue is resolved, I added allow_url_fopen. Thanks for your help !